# Integrating Sin[x]^k for positive integer k?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, trigonometry

I am looking to integrate some expressions containing trigonometric functions raised to general powers (which get messy, I know). However, I am struggling to make much headway.

As a simple test case, consider

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^k, x]
```

For `k = 2` the result we should obtain is

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^2, x]
```

> ```
> x/2 - 1/4 Sin[2 x]
> ```

```
Plot[x/2 - 1/4 Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: plot of integral]

Now to try for general `k`, then afterwards set `k = 2` and hope to recover the above simple result. Note, I am only ever interested in integers `k >= 1`.

```
int = Integrate[Sin[x]^k, x]
```

> ```
> -Cos[x] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (1 - k)/2, 3/2, Cos[x]^2]
>  Sin[x]^(1 + k) (Sin[x]^2)^(1/2 (-1 - k))
> ```

```
Plot[int /. k -> 2, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: discontinuous plot]

The result isn't the same...?

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to correctly integrate `Sin[x]^k` / shed some light on whats going awry here?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the power $\sin ^k x$  is a complex number if $\sin x <0$ and $k>0$. This causes a problem.

Comment: This is well understood. I'll try to find the blog post somewhere, but that second result is *an* antiderivative of the function, because they can be discontinuous. You have to be careful with indefinite integrals.

Comment: But anyway, do the definite integral version: `Integrate[Sin[xt]^2, {xt, 0, x}]`.

Comment: Maybe it's [this one](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/)?

Comment: `f[x_, k_] := -Cos[x] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (1 - k)/2, 3/2, 
   Cos[x]^2] Sin[x]^(
  1 + k) (Sin[x]^2)^(-(1/2) - k/2); Plot[{0.79 + 
   Piecewise[{{f[x, 2], 0 < x < Pi}, {f[x, 2] + Pi/2, 
      Pi < x < 2*Pi}}], x/2 - 1/4 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Black, Dashed}}]`

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk : The question is: how to derive it?

Comment: Perhaps I should have stressed that I am only interested in `k ∈ Integers` and `k >= 1` - i.e. no chance of complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you always want $k$ to be an integer, you could run `TrigReduce` on the function before integrating:

```
f[x_, k_Integer] := Integrate[TrigReduce[Sin[x]^k], x]

f[x, 2]
(* x/2 - 1/4 Sin[2 x] *)

f[x, 5]
(* -((5 Cos[x])/8) + 5/48 Cos[3 x] - 1/80 Cos[5 x] *)
```

Since these results only contain nicely behaved sine & cosine formulas, they will not have any discontinuities.

---

Internally, BTW, Mathematica is probably using some version of the following identities to apply `TrigReduce`:

$$
\sin^{2n-1} A = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-2}} \left[ \sin (2n - 1)A - {2n-1 \choose 1} \sin (2n - 3) A + \cdots (-1)^{n-1} {2n-1 \choose n-1} \sin A\right]
$$
$$
\sin^{2n} A \\= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n \choose n} + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{2n-1}} \left[ \cos 2nA - {2n \choose 1} \cos (2n - 2) A + \cdots (-1)^{n-1} {2n \choose n-1} \cos 2 A\right]
$$
These identities can be most easily derived by writing $\sin^k x = [(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})/2i]^k$, expanding via the binomial theorem, and pairing off terms of the form $e^{inx}$ and $e^{-inx}$.
It would be easy enough to write down an exact expression for the integrals of these sums.

Comment: The Wolfram Functions site has [these formulae](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/16/07/05/) of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is a substitute:

```
int1=Integrate[Sin[t]^k, t,Assumptions -> t >= Pi && k>0] + Integrate[Sin[t]^k, {t, 0, Pi}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[[Pi]] Gamma[(1 + k)/2])/Gamma[1 + k/2] - 
>     Cos[t]*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (1 - k)/2, 3/2, Cos[t]^2] Sin[t]^(
>      1 + k) (Sin[t]^2)^(1/2 (-1 - k)), Re[k] > -1]

```
p = Plot[int1 /. k -> 2, {t, Pi, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

and so on, e.g.

```
int2=Integrate[Sin[t]^k,t,Assumptions ->t>= 2*Pi && k>0]+ Integrate[Sin[t]^k,{t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Addition. The above is a shifted plot of

> x/2 - 1/4 Sin[2 x]

on $[\pi,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work:

```
f[n_Integer?Positive,x_]:=If[EvenQ[n],
    -Cos[x] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2,1/2-n/2,3/2,Cos[x]^2] Sign[Sin[x]] +
       (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[(1+n)/2] (1+2 Floor[x/\[Pi]] HeavisideTheta[x]))/(2 (n/2)!),
    -Cos[x] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2,1/2-n/2,3/2,Cos[x]^2]
]
```

Check :

```
With[{k=10},Plot[Evaluate[f[k,x]- Integrate[Sin[x]^k,x]],{x,0,10Pi}]]
With[{k=11},Plot[Evaluate[f[k,x]- Integrate[Sin[x]^k,x]],{x,0,10Pi}]]
```

[image]